# Can a standard USB device use WinUSB to establish communication

Tags: windows, winusb

It seems to be an unbelievable story. Please help. 
I want to develop a windows tool to communicate with HID device. However, it's not possible for me to modify the HID device usage table (report descriptor is fixed). And now, I need to send a vendor defined command (which is not included in device usage table) to the USB device.
There's specific API for HID device (set feature, get feature, etc. ). However, it seems not possible to send command which is not in usage table. I doubt whether in this case WinUsb is possible to help. The main problem is --each article I find is to create a new driver (.INF). Is  WinUSB  functional if my USB device remain to use HID driver?

Thanks  everybody in advance.

Comment: You need to create a kernel mode driver if you want to send a command that's not in the usage table. You've run into the same problem that using a PlayStation 3 controller on Windows runs into. The PS3 controller needs to be sent a special command before it starts working but that command isn't in the usage table. So you need a install a third party driver to get it work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it a requirement to use winusb driver instead of standard driver? I prefer to keep standard driver, as it's convenient for customer to use.

Comment: Is kernel mode the  requirement to use WinUSB, or is it the requirement comes from "send a special command before it starts working"?

Comment: You need to create a kernel mode driver if you want to send a command to an HID device that's not in the HID device's usage table. You cannot use WinUSB.